# C++ How to execute a "RESET SESSION" command

Tags: c++, windows, cmd, logout

I need to create in C ++ a service that terminates the session of all logged users  in after a certain time.

On the console I can simply type:

```
RESET SESSION console
```

or

```
RESET SESSION <int id>
```

But when I try to execute this command in the service code, run exe as administrator:

```
system("RESET SESSION console");
```

I get message that RESET is not a valid internal command.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Are you using a special terminal to start a _session_?

Comment: 1. maybe nos-standard terminal (like @πάνταῥεῖ say), 2. different permisssions for service

Comment: I am running on a Windows 10 Enterprise machine. I'm not testing as a service yet. Only by running, as administrator, a c ++ application that tries to execute the command. So the access rights of the services is not important yet. Yes, it may have to do with access rights of the applications, but the message should not be another?

Comment: Probably you built a 32-bit application, for which `system` executes 32-bit cmd.exe, for which System32 gets redirected to SysWOW64, which has the 32-bit system binaries. reset.exe is only distributed as a 64-bit executable in the real System32 folder. A 32-bit application can access this via the virtual path `%SystemRoot%\SysNative\reset.exe`.

Comment: Thanks eryksun, I think you are right. Do you know what can i do to built in Visual Studio a 64-bit application?

Comment: system("%SystemRoot%\\SysNative\\RESET SESSION console");works well.Thank you eryksun.